# Copying from one drive to another / filename too long?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Copying folders on a Windows 10 machine from one drive to another in File Explorer fails with the following error:

> "the file name(s) would be too long for the destination folder."

Both drives are the same size and use the same format. How can it fit on the source but not on the destination?

Comment: how many characters is one of those filenames?

Comment: I don't know cause the msg only shows me the folder and I don't know which of the files it refers to

Comment: @Abi - Use the command prompt to determine the information requested.  The solution, of course, is to shorten the length of the path.  How you accomplish that is entirely up to you.

Comment: I think " File Explorer, does not support LongPathsEnabled" explains everything!!

Answer (score 0):

[*Long Path Fixer*](http://corz.org/windows/software/accessories/Long-Path-Fixer-for-Windows.php) claims to *Move*, *Copy* and *Delete* files with full path up to 32,767 characters. Though I've not used it, it's free, portable and tested clean at VirusTotal. [If it works for your use, please comment so this answer may be improved.]

According to a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/320801/alternative-to-windows-explorer-for-long-path-names), *FAR Manager* can *access* files with long paths... though with limitations.

Answer (score -1):

Windows does have a 260 character filename limit. Have a go at editing the registry to bypass this limit by following the instructions found [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/)

Comment: But how did it fit on the source drive ?

Comment: @Abi - `File Explorer` is what has the path length limitation.

Comment: We always appreciate the contributions from our community members, but please [do not provide answers that are only a hyperlink](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). While the information may be valuable, if the source web page ever goes offline the answer is essentially useless. Quote all of the pertinent excerpts from the article within your answer, then you can still provide the hyperlink to cite your source. Please see the following article from our Help Center:  [How do I write a good answer?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Indeed i am sorry. Will adhere to answering etiquette more closely next time. Thanks.