# Windows 10 Long File Names

Tags: windows-10, filenames

I built a new computer from ebay scraps after my laptop died. I began transferring files from my old hard drive (Windows XP to Windows 10) and ran into an issue where I could not either move or delete some of my old files. I received an error that file names were too long.

1. First I tried renaming the files.

   Result: For some reason, the files would not rename. I checked and they were not Read Only...A weird mystery.
2. I researched this forum and changed Windows to accept Long File Paths.

   Result: While the long file paths were a contributing factor, the real issue were the names of the files themselves. I still couldn't move or delete these files.

There had to be some legacy setting that allows long file names (example: royalty-free-photograph-of-student-chemistry-biology-bottle-science-BGBB5A)

The question is this: Is there a legacy setting in Windows 10 that will allow me to work with these files?

Comment: 7-Zip can rename the long files

Comment: `royalty-free-photograph-of-student-chemistry-biology-bottle-science-BGBB5A` is not long at all. It's long compared to DOS 8.3 names but is far from Win32 limit of 255 characters. The issue is long file **path**, not long file **name**, which the built-in robocopy can handle without any problem

Comment: just add the \\?\ prefix with `copy` command, or use another tool to copy. There are lots of duplicates: [How to copy files that have too long of a filepath in Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/216704/241386), [Copying from one drive to another / filename too long?](https://superuser.com/q/1355853/241386), [How to prevent long file name error copying from an external drive?](https://superuser.com/q/349531/241386)...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy files that have too long of a filepath in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/216704/how-to-copy-files-that-have-too-long-of-a-filepath-in-windows)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to [manipulate them using the old 8.3 filename](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/cant-delete-long-filenames/), which is available from CMD. For example, enter `dir /` at root and you should see the following.

[image: CMD to manipulate long filenames]

You can perform operations such as copy or delete on `PROGRA~2`, a synonym for `Program Files (x86)`, for example.

You can also use wild cards, particularly helpful where a filename has an illegal character.

That said, often the issue is an **excessively long path**, i.e. drive + full file path + filename longer than 260 characters. You can make Windows 10 handle longer paths by [setting the Registry value `LongPathsEnabled`](https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/) in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem` to `1`, or back to `0` to revert behavior.

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `rege` and select *Regedit*.
- Accept the UAC prompt.
- In the location bar, enter `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem` (copy and paste from here to make it easier) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- If the value `LongPathsEnabled` does not show in the right pane, right-click, select `New>` `New DWORD (32-bit) Value`, and copy the value name above.
- Double-click the value and set it to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround (Windows 10) was to 1) enable long file paths in Windows and 2) use the WSL2 bash command `cp -R` to do the actual copying.  (I am not sure if step 1) was necessary, but the combination worked for me).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).